# How to reload JDialog in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, jradiobutton

Hello I've problem in reloading `JDialog`.
I've 2 JRadioButton:

- Not defined
- Defined in first row

When I click a button, a dialog will appear, it's content will depend on the radio button. If I choose the first one it will display "Hello World!", but if I choose the second will display "Hello Community!". But the dialog won't change, just display the content based on what I choose first.

Here is my button action:

```
txtResult.setText(radioOption.getSelectedItem().toString());
JDialog jd = new JDialog();
jd.setSize(600,400); 
jd.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: can you provide SSCCE(Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)

Comment: Need more code than 4 lines ...

Comment: Sorry for the too simple example, `txtResult` is `JTextField` which will display the result.

Comment: Sorry all, the problem is not on the `JDialog` nor `JRadioButton` but on `JTable` (it's my original case, in this sample I don't give you case that my `JDialog` containing `JTable`)

Comment: @FahmiRamadhan Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so that there will be no confusion and people can answer your question precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is documentation and I suggest you (not just you) try to read before write any code, 
[Link to examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#RadioButtonDemo) first line your example, [link to doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, radioOption.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

In above code `frame` is owner window

EDIT :

And in your code as you have commented `txtResult` is `JTextField` so the `radioOption` text will **display** on `JTextField` not on any `dialogbox`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting
    jd.dispose();
at the end of your code. This will remove the message object.